# Can Materialized View fast refresh work when based on views are based on tables?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I am reviewing my team's database setup, particularly focusing on Materialized Views. In most cases, we are currently doing 'Complete' refreshes, and I want to move to doing fast refreshes.

In some cases, this is straight forward -- the MV is based directly on a table on our source database, and I can enable MVIEW LOGS on the table and recreate the MV.

But in a number of cases, the MVs are based on a combination of other MVs, and Views, etc, that go several levels deep before I get to the tables on our source database.

In these cases, if I track down the ultimate source tables, will enabling MVIEW LOGS on them allow the top MV and any intermediate MVs, to use fast refresh?

Answer (score 3):

The [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#i1007007) contains an example for a `FAST REFRESH` of a materialized view based on an `UNION ALL` view:

```
CREATE VIEW view_with_unionall AS
(SELECT c.rowid crid, c.cust_id, 2 umarker
 FROM customers c WHERE c.cust_last_name = 'Smith'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT c.rowid crid, c.cust_id, 3 umarker
 FROM customers c WHERE c.cust_last_name = 'Jones');

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW unionall_inside_view_mv
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND AS
SELECT * FROM view_with_unionall;
```

So in principle, you can indeed fast refresh materialized views based on views.

Some things to note:

- there are a couple of restrictions for fast refreshable materialized views. E.g. you cannot use `ROWNUM`, `SYSDATE` or `HAVING`. See the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm#i1007007) for details
- somewhat counterintuitively, a `FAST REFRESH` is not always faster than a `COMPLETE REFRESH`. This depends on the amount of data that has changed since the last refresh; IMHO, Oracle should have used the term `INCREMENTAL REFRESH` instead

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides a procedure for that: [DBMS_MVIEW.EXPLAIN_MVIEW](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_mview.htm#CEGGEHHC)

You can use this procedure to check whether your Materialized Views is capable for `FAST REFRESH`, it also tells you the reason why it is not.

For me the most strange restriction for `FAST REFRESH` is: When you join several tables you have to use the (old) Oracle Join syntax, ANSI join syntax does not work. Some time ago a created a case at Oracle support for this issue, however the answer from Oracle was: "This is not a bug, it is just a lack of documentation."(!)

I don't know if it still applies for Oracle 12c version.